# Merge rows (string) in a dataset according to IDs

Tags: python

My dataset has 2 columns - Colid is a column with ids and ColB is a string column (with some texts).
I need to merge texts according to ids. If null, just keep the one that is not null. If both are null, then return null

df

```
Colid ColB       
1     bla bla   
1     text   
2     hi
2     hello 
3     bye
3     null
4     null
```

Output I need

new_df

```
Colid     ColB       
    1     bla bla text   
    2     hi hello
    3     bye
    4     null
```

Could someone help do that in python, please?

Answer (score 0):

You could just loop over the rows of your dataset, construct a dictionary of ids and collate the texts:

```
d = {}
for i in range(len(df['Colid']):
    try:
        d[df['Colid'][i]] += ' ' + df['ColB'][i]
    except:
        d[df['Colid'][i]] = df['ColB'][i]
    if d[df['Colid'][i]] == 'null null': d[df['Colid'][i]] = 'null'
    if 'null' in d[df['Colid'][i]] and len(d[df['Colid'][i]]) > 4: d[df['Colid'][i]] = d[df['Colid'][i]].replace('null','')
```

Using `d.items()` you get a zipped list of `Colid` values and concatenated strings that you can easily make into a new dataframe in whatever framework you use.

Comment: Looping is almost always the wrong answer when it comes to dataframes. It is much more performant (and also usually a shorter code) to use vecorization